# How to get Eclipse to compile files from "test/src" instead of "src" directory when building (using built in builders)?

Tags: android, eclipse, build

Can an android project in Eclipse be configured so that the built-in builders read from an alternative source directory?  ie. "test/src" instead of "src"?  and possibly even "test/res" instead of "res"?  (It appears that setting dirs in the property files will only affect ant and not the built-in builders)

If this can be done ... how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to right click to the project and select Build Path->Configure Build Path then from source add your desired folder?